# mysqldump --where clause is not working as expected

Tags: mysql

I want to take the dump only of the latest rows. But When i pass the --where option its not dumping the rows. but when i execute select query with the same where clause it returns the rows. here is my select query:

```
SELECT  * FROM abc.`xyz` WHERE UPDATED_AT >="2015-11-11 10:03:37";
```

here is my mysqldump command:

```
 mysqldump --no-create-info --replace -h source_server --user=backup1 --password='passcode' abc xyz --where='UPDATED_AT >="2015-11-11 10:03:37"'  > "backup.sql"
```

What is the problem in the above mysqldump command why its not dumping the records?

dump file portion is as under:

```
 --
 -- Dumping data for table `xyz`
 --
 -- WHERE:  UPDATED_AT >='2015-11-11 10:03:37'

 LOCK TABLES `xyz` WRITE;
 /*!40000 ALTER TABLE `xyz` DISABLE KEYS */;
 /*!40000 ALTER TABLE `xyz` ENABLE KEYS */;
 UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Comment: it works fine when i remove  `where`

Comment: Then the `where` condition really is the problem.  Right now, it is never returning true.

Comment: UPDATED_AT is a timestamp not a datetime. Should i give it a try to change the field type?

Comment: It worked fine when I updated the field type from timestamp to datetime.

Comment: Hang on...let's find a way to keep things the same and convert from timestamp to datetime in the actual `mysqldump` command.

Comment: that would be really nice as a lot of tables i have to sync on the server. those have same field type.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen your propsed unix_timestamp() worked well with MySQL5.0.5

Comment: I butchered my answer too many times to take credit.  Please update your own answer and then mark it correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In where clause the `UPDATED_AT` field type was timestamp I changed the field type to DATETIME. It worked as expected.

For the latest version above field type changing works but for the mysql 5.0.5 
`FROM_UNIXTIME` works.

Comment: FROM_UNIXTIME returned all the rows.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command:

```
mysqldump --tz-utc=0 --no-create-info --replace -h source_server --user=backup1 --password='passcode' abc xyz --where='UPDATED_AT >="2015-11-11 10:03:37"'  > "backup.sql"
```